Google Ads API, campaign status integer?
I'm using the Google Ads API, and with the docs about the status:
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/v17/CampaignStatusEnum.CampaignStatus
It show that is a ENUM with string values. But when I do the query:
 SELECT
                    campaign.id,
                    campaign.name,
                    campaign.status,
                    campaign.start_date,
                    campaign.end_date
                FROM campaign
                ORDER BY campaign.name

the status show a number between 1 and 4 (at least that numbers I see, idk if is more options).
Any have a documentation about what means each number? or if i'm missing something in the query to get string enum?
Thanks

I found it.
//Google\Ads\GoogleAds\V17\Enums\CampaignStatusEnum\CampaignStatus;

class CampaignStatus
{
    const UNSPECIFIED = 0;
    const UNKNOWN = 1;
    const ENABLED = 2;
    const PAUSED = 3;
    const REMOVED = 4;

.....
}

